# Why Is the content Inside my div popping out?

Tags: html, css

I Have a div (RView) that has other div content inside but unlike my other divs when the page shrinks in width the content doesn't reshape it pops out of the div. Why is this?, I want the images to the left of the text & all conntent in a line like it currently is but not popping out the div. Also this is my first ever attempt at building a website so I know it's no where near perfect but I'm still learning.

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
}

.RView {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #BEBFBE;
    justify-content: center;
    display: flex;
}

.RView div {
    display: flex;
}

.RView p {
    margin: 20px 0px 0px 20px;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 150px;
}

.ReVW {
    display: inherit;
    width: 105px;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 20px 0px 20px 80px;
}
```

```html
<div class="RView">
    <div><a href="https://www.cnet.com/uk/reviews/"><img src="Img/CNet.png" class="ReVW" alt="CNet Review"></a><p>"Incredibly beautiful phone case for an affordable price" - CNet</p></div>
    <div><a href="https://www.amazon.co.uk/ref=nav_logo/262-3052852-5868165"><img src="Img/AMZN.png" class="ReVW" alt="Amazon Review"></a><p>"Definetly some new competition on the market for the phone case industry" - Amazon</p></div>
    <div><a href="http://www.techadvisor.co.uk/review/phone-cases/"><img src="Img/RV1.png" class="ReVW" alt="Bolt Review"></a><p>"Wide range of case designs for any phone, just amazing cases" - Bolt Reviews</p></div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the columns inside a flex container to be flex, rather than a flex column.

The below will set them to be equal width columns, and should stop the content overflowing.

```
.RView div {
    flex:1;
}
```

Here is updated css to show the images next to the text content, with margins reset.

```
.RView p {
    margin: 0;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 50%;
}

.ReVW {
   width: 50%;
   margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately text is not next to image now

Comment: P tag by default is a block level element, setting .RView p {display: inline-block;} would give it the ability to have the image next to the text.Without knowing the size of your containers, you would have to play around with your widths of your .RView p & .ReVW selectors.  taking into account the margins as well.